Converting From UWP To WinUI - Gridsplitter Control Template
I am converting my UWP app to WinUI and .Net 8.0.  I have a control template for a GridSplitter that uses the GridSplitter.Element to create a control template that includes a Grid and two Buttons.  In WinUI it tells me the Element tag is not valid. I have not found examples of GridSplitter Style or Control Templates for WinUI.  Can I still create a custom control template for a GridSplitter in WinUI?  The reason for the template is to have a static Window in the left pane and a changeable page in the right pane based on one of the button clicks.  I have not figured out a work around but could find one if I cannot control template the GridSplitter.
I have not tried a work around but it would be to go back to a base GridSplitter and place the buttons that displayed each page in a different place.

The GridSplitter comes from Windows Community Toolkit. To use the GridSplitter, you need to install the CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls.Sizers NuGet package.
Now, to re-template the GridSplitter control, you need to understand that it derives from SizerBase. In the SizerBase's default Style, you can see that it has a Grid named RootGrid, and a Rectangle named PART_Thumb.
Here's an example:
<Page
    x:Class="GridSplitterDemo.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:GridSplitterDemo"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style
            x:Key="CustomGridSplitter"
            TargetType="toolkit:GridSplitter">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:GridSplitter">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                            <Rectangle
                                x:Name="PART_Thumb"
                                Width="4"
                                Height="8"
                                Fill="SkyBlue" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto,*">
        <Button
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Content="Left" />
        <toolkit:GridSplitter
            Grid.Column="1"
            Style="{StaticResource CustomGridSplitter}" />
        <Button
            Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Content="Right" />
    </Grid>

</Page>


Thank you for the response.  I though about using a Style but wanted confirmation this is the correct solution.  I have coded the Style but still have some work to get my UWP app to be WinUI compatible so I have not been able to test it yet.  More work than I thought this would be it makes me wonder if I did it right in UWP to have this much work to convert to WinUI.
